# Firestore paginated document list weird behaviour in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, chat

I am a newbie to Flutter and building a chat app to practice with firestore. I have implemented pagination for the data but there is weird behavior that I am seeing and have currently no solution for it. When I sync a list of documents, they are listed in perfect order. But when I put the app in the background for a long time and then pull it in the foreground, the order of some of the items comes incorrect. I have seen this happen multiple times, if the app is in background and the list is updated on firestore and I put the app in foreground, some of the previously synced messages come to the end of the list, e.g., if I sync a list of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and put the app in background and reopen it then sometimes the data would look like 1,2,4,5,6,7,3. I am attaching the code used for it.

**ChatWidget:**

```
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();
  .....
  _chatViewModel.getMessages();
  _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
} 

.............

void _scrollListener() async {
  _chatViewModel.getOldMessages(_scrollController.position.pixels,
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
}

.............

child: StreamBuilder(
     stream: _chatViewModel.messageStream,
     builder: (context, snapshot) =>_setListWidget(snapshot))

.............

Widget _setListWidget(AsyncSnapshot<List<MessageV2>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          controller: _scrollController,
          reverse: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return MessageWidget(msg: snapshot.data![index]);
          });
    } else {
      return Center(child: Text('No data...'));
    }
  }
```

**ChatViewModel:**

I added a HashSet recently as fail-safe measure to prevent this behavior but still happens.

```
late Stream<List<MessageV2>> messageStream;
final StreamController<List<MessageV2>> _messageStreamProvidor = StreamController();
final _messageList = <MessageV2>[];

ChatViewModel(){
......
messageStream = _messageStreamProvidor.stream;
_messageStreamProvidor.add(_messageList);
}

getMessages() {
    _dbService.messages.listen((list) {
      try {
        var list1 = <MessageV2>[];
        for (var element in list) {
          if (!_messageSet.contains(element.id)) {
            list1.add(element);
            _messageSet.add(element.id);
          }
        }
        _messageList.insertAll(0, list1);
        _messageStreamProvidor.add(_messageList);
        _viewStateStreamProvidor.add(ViewState.viewVisible);
        if (list.isNotEmpty && (list.first.isMe || _count == 0)) {
          if (_count == 0) _count++;
          _scrollStreamProvidor.add(true);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
  }

//Method to fetch the old messages.
getOldMessages(double pixels, double maxScrollExtent) async {
    if (pixels == maxScrollExtent && !_dbService.loading) {
      _messageLoaderProvidor.add(_dbService.loading);
      final list = await _dbService.getOldMessageListSnapshot();
      if (list != null && list.isNotEmpty) {
        for (var e in list) {
          if (!_messageSet.contains(e.id)) {
            _messageList.add(e);
            _messageSet.add(e.id);
          }
        }
        _messageStreamProvidor.add(_messageList);
        _messageLoaderProvidor.add(_dbService.loading);
      }
    }
  }
```

**DatabaseService:**

```
Stream<List<MessageV2>> get messages {
    return _messageCollection
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(_messageLimit)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_messageListFromSnapshot);
}

List<MessageV2> _messageListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    final list = <MessageV2>[];
    _lastDoc ??= snapshot.docs.last;
    for (var e in snapshot.docChanges) {
      switch (e.type) {
        case DocumentChangeType.added:
          list.add(MessageV2.fromMap(e.doc, uid, true));
          print('added');
          break;
        case DocumentChangeType.modified:
          print('modified');
          break;
        case DocumentChangeType.removed:
          print('removed');
          break;
      }
    }
    return list;
 }

Future<List<MessageV2>?> getOldMessageListSnapshot() async {
    if (!loading && _lastDoc != null) {
      loading = true;
      var data = await _messageCollection
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(_lastDoc!)
          .limit(_messageLimit)
          .get();
      loading = false;
      if (data.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        _lastDoc = data.docs.last;
        return _setChatListFromQuerySnapshot(data);
      }
    }
    loading = false;
    return null;
  }
```

The code works absolutely fine when it stays in foreground. I can send and receive messages in perfect order and pagination is also correct. Only when it stays in background for a long time it starts displaying this behavior. I have tried multiple things to fix this but it keeps creeping back. Am I supposed to clear the stream when app geos in background and re-register it when it comes to foreground? I am a bit clueless here.